Load all Angular Material Style in single CSS file, instead of loading style at runtime
In my Angular 8 Application multiple style tags are getting generated at runtime for Angular Material. I want to add some CSP attribute all my style tag after build is completed.
For that I want my all Angular Material style to load during build time only. and It should not generate any style tag in DOM at runtime. Can We do that?
added prebuilt theme in angular.json

Angular adds style tags to the HTML document for component styles. So the framework must offer some solution for CSP, which is unfortunately not the case in Angular 8.
Starting from Angular 16, you can register a nonce for the styles. There are two options:

Add the ngCspNonce attribute to your app root tag in the index.html: <app-root ngCspNonce="YOUR_NONCE"></app-root>
Provide a value for the CSP_NONCE injection token in your app.module.ts (or app.config.ts for standalone workspaces)

Afterwards, you can add CSP headers with that nonce. For more information, see the security docs.

Need solution for angular 8

@TechGeek As I have explained in my answer, there is no solution for Angular 8. You need to update Angular, which you should do anyway for several other reasons.

There is solution. In vendor.js file of dist folder, post-build we can run some node.js script which will add nonce attribute where it is adding stylenodes to dom. that will work any way. But Instead I am just find some way so that I can directly add nonce to style itself.
